# How can peer admin create a channel when it does not have permissions to write to orderer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

In all of the [fabric-samples](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples) the creation of a channel is done by a peer admin user. However this user does not even have permissions to write to the orderer. So how can it succeed? Taking a specific example of [first-network](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/first-network/docker-compose-cli.yaml):

```
- CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
- CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
```

so the channel creation is executed under org1's admin credentials. But when we look at [configtx.yaml](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/first-network/configtx.yaml):

```
 - &OrdererOrg
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: OrdererOrg

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: OrdererMSP

        # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration
        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"
```

in order to write to the orderer one has to be `OrdererMSP.member` which clearly org1's admin is not. So how can it pass the policy check?

When we try to develop an application using the pattern in fabric-samples, we get error while trying to create a channel under peer admin credentials:

```
2019-03-12 17:05:09.337 UTC [orderer/common/msgprocessor] ProcessConfigUpdateMsg -> DEBU 0d9 Processing config update message for channel dscsa
2019-03-12 17:05:09.337 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 0da == Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Writers ==
2019-03-12 17:05:09.337 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 0db This is an implicit meta policy, it will trigger other policy evaluations, whose failures may be benign
2019-03-12 17:05:09.337 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 0dc == Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Orderer/Writers ==
2019-03-12 17:05:09.337 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 0dd This is an implicit meta policy, it will trigger other policy evaluations, whose failures may be benign
2019-03-12 17:05:09.337 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 0de == Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Orderer/ord/Writers ==
2019-03-12 17:05:09.337 UTC [msp] DeserializeIdentity -> DEBU 0df Obtaining identity
2019-03-12 17:05:09.337 UTC [msp/identity] newIdentity -> DEBU 0e0 Creating identity instance for cert -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
2019-03-12 17:05:09.338 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 0e1 0xc42000e1e8 gate 1552410309337999686 evaluation starts
2019-03-12 17:05:09.338 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 0e2 0xc42000e1e8 signed by 0 principal evaluation starts (used [false])
2019-03-12 17:05:09.338 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 0e3 0xc42000e1e8 processing identity 0 with bytes of ...
2019-03-12 17:05:09.338 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 0e4 0xc42000e1e8 identity 0 does not satisfy principal: the identity is a member of a different MSP (expected ordMSP, got org1MSP)
2019-03-12 17:05:09.338 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 0e5 0xc42000e1e8 principal evaluation fails
2019-03-12 17:05:09.338 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 0e6 0xc42000e1e8 gate 1552410309337999686 evaluation fails
2019-03-12 17:05:09.338 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 0e7 Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Orderer/ord/Writers
2019-03-12 17:05:09.338 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 0e8 == Done Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Orderer/ord/Writers
2019-03-12 17:05:09.338 UTC [policies] func1 -> DEBU 0e9 Evaluation Failed: Only 0 policies were satisfied, but needed 1 of [ ord.Writers ]
2019-03-12 17:05:09.338 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 0ea Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Orderer/Writers
2019-03-12 17:05:09.338 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 0eb == Done Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Orderer/Writers
2019-03-12 17:05:09.338 UTC [policies] func1 -> DEBU 0ec Evaluation Failed: Only 0 policies were satisfied, but needed 1 of [ Orderer.Writers Consortiums.Writers ]
2019-03-12 17:05:09.338 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 0ed Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Writers
2019-03-12 17:05:09.338 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 0ee == Done Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Writers
2019-03-12 17:05:09.338 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> WARN 0ef [channel: dscsa] Rejecting broadcast of config message from 10.0.0.192:54232 because of error: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining: permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you got your answer by now as it is 11 months old question. If not, here is my explanation. The policies for Orderer org is to read, make changes to the Orderer organization/ orderer system channel. Not to the application channels. Ord1 admin can make changes as that is defined in the Application section's policies of confitx.yaml which is ImplecitMeta constructed from the participating Orgs's Signature policies.

I hope it helps.